# psql server not listen port 5432 though it's in postgresql.conf

Tags: postgresql, connection, port

When no SSL configs applied :

pg_hba.conf 
host  database  user 0.0.0.0/0  scram-sha-256

```
 postgresql.conf   
 listen_addresses = ‘*’
 port = 5432
 ssl = on
 ssl_cert_file =  ‘/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem’
 ssl_key_file = ‘/wtc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key’
```

I get : netstat -nltp

```
  smadmin@studymatepro:~$ sudo netstat -nltp

  Active Internet connections (only servers)
  Proto    Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address  Foreign Address  State program name    
  tcp        0      0      127.0.0.53:53    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN 970/systemd-resolve 
  tcp        0      0      0.0.0.0:22       0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      1405/sshd           
  tcp        0      0      127.0.0.1:631    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      1079/cupsd          
  tcp        0      0     0.0.0.0:5432     0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      3780/postgres       
  tcp6       0      0      :::22             :::*       LISTEN      1405/sshd           
  tcp6       0      0       ::1:631          :::*       LISTEN      1079/cupsd          
  tcp6       0      0       :::5432          :::*       LISTEN      3780/postgres       
   smadmin@studymatepro:~$
```

you can see the remote tcp/ip on port 5432  ; and can get SSL connection (server side authentication only)

Now , when I configure SSL , and add client.crt,client.key & root.crt to the client machine  :

pg_hba.conf

```
hostssl  database  user 0.0.0.0/0  scram-sha-256  clientcert=1
```

postgresql.conf

```
   listen_addresses = ‘*’
   port = 5432
   ssl = on
   ssl_cert_file =  ‘/etc/ssl/certs/server.crt’  // my self signed crt 
   ssl_key_file = ‘/etc/ssl/private/server.key’
   ssl_ca_file = ‘/etc/ssl/certs/rootCert.crt’
   ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on
   ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'
   password_encryption = scram-sha-256
```

and do : netstat -nltp  ; I get

```
    Active Internet connections (only servers)
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address    Foreign Address  State PID/Program name    
    tcp        0      0  127.0.0.53:53       0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      970/systemd-resolve 
    tcp        0      0  0.0.0.0:22          0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      1405/sshd           
    tcp        0      0  127.0.0.1:631       0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      1079/cupsd          
    tcp6       0      0  :::22                :::*         LISTEN      1405/sshd           
    tcp6       0      0  ::1:631              :::*         LISTEN      1079/cupsd
```

The remote TCP/IP on port 5432 gone !!! and thats why I’m getting the connection refused since remote port 5432 are no longer active .
The question is why this happined ...I’m I doing some wrong ?

Comment: If the `netstat` was run on the server machine, I'd take it as an indication that the PostgreSQL server is not started.

Comment: @Laurenz Alba ....Actually " systemctl restart postgresql.service " I do in almost all steps.

Comment: Yes, but how do you know that the server actually started?

Comment: @Laurenz Alba ... I'v been testing the connection with & without SSL configurations , and noticed the above results ..I mentioned in the question area ..it's like revised full stack of the problem.

Comment: Look into the PostgreSQL log file.